# How to trigger color dialog from js code

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<input type="color" id="colorDialogID">
<div id="textToColorID">Text to color</div>
<input type="button" id="setColorButtonID">
```

and I want to by clicking on button to display color dialog. And when I select particular color and press on 'ok', some text to get the selected color.

I need `js` code for this. I am googling almost one hour now to find a way how to display code picker window from code and no success. I get only kind of plugins. I can not understand why everything has to be so complicated with `javascript`.

Comment: Share some of your `js` code so that we can see what you're trying to do.  Question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for future reference it is always good to provide a snippet of your code - or even better a JSFiddle link but this is what I've got now.

```js
document.getElementById("setColorButtonID").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").focus();
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value = "#FFCC00"; //Set the default color  NOTE: Remove the line to get the default of #000000
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").click();
});

function getColor() {
  var color = document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value;
  document.getElementById("textToColorID").style.color = color;
}
```

```css
#colorDialogID {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="colorDialogID" onchange="getColor(this)">
<div id="textToColorID">Text to color</div>
<input type="button" id="setColorButtonID" value="Edit Color">
```

I can add some comments to the code to explain it line by line if you wish - but this should work.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I need a button because it is the simplest way to show me how to trigger-call  "color picker dialog box" from javascript code. And i don't want to use color picker as button because it does not look as a button. Users will not see it as a button. And why should i work on css to change color picker button.

Comment: And i use prompt dialog where i instruct the user of my app: "Chose the color for...." So, after "ok" is clicked the color picker has to appear.

Comment: @ivangolubar See my above edit. You can also run the code by clicking the 'Run Code snippet' button at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/). It's dead simple and the functionality that you're looking for can be easily reached.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>

Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```